# What is the preferred way of expanding twice in expl3?

Tags: expansion, expl3, l3keys

`expl3` includes the `o`, `f`, and `x` argument specifiers for one-level and the two kinds of full expansion, respectively, before passing the argument to the base function.  What is the preferred way of expanding an argument *twice* before passing it to the base function?

As an example, I'm trying to write a `l3keys` key-value interface to macros created with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from the `mathtools` package.

```
\tl_new:N \l__mymodule_size_tl
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
  {
    size .choices:nn =
      { big , Big , bigg , Bigg }
      {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__mymodule_size_tl
          { [ \use:c { \tl_use:N \l_keys_choice_tl } ] }
      } ,

    size / auto .code:n = 
      \tl_set:Nn \l__mymodule_size_tl {*} ,

    size / none .code:n = 
      \tl_clear:N \l__mymodule_size_tl
  }
```

Usually, the size of the delimiters is passed to the macro as an optional argument of `\big` etc. or `*`, such as `\abs[\big]{x}` where `\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}`.  I would prefer to have `size = big` etc. or `size = auto` as a key-value interface, such as `\myabs[size=big]{x}`.

The problem with the above code comes in correctly setting `\l__mymodule_size_tl` in the `big` etc. choices: I need to expand `[ \use:c { \tl_use:N \l_keys_choice_tl } ]` *twice* before assigning those tokens to `\l__mymodule_size_tl`.

- If I use no expansion (i.e., `\tl_set:Nn`), the call to `\abs` gets its argument in the wrong form -- `\l__mymodule_size_tl` will hold `[ \use:c { \tl_use:N \l_keys_choice_tl } ]`, not `[\big]`.
- If I use one-level expansion (i.e., `\tl_set:No`) and prepend `[` after the expansion is complete, `\l__mymodule_size_tl` will hold `[ \cs:w \tl_use:N \l_keys_choice_tl \cs_end: ]`, not `[\big]`.
- If I use either `f` or `x` expansion, `\l__mymodule_size_tl` will hold a bunch of "garbage", not `[\big]`.

What can I do?  Here is an idea: Use two `o` expansions, with some acrobatics between.

```
    \tl_set:No \l__mymodule_size_tl
      { \use:c { \tl_use:N \l_keys_choice_tl } ] }
    \exp_args:NNV \tl_set:No \l__mymodule_size_tl 
      \l__mymodule_size_tl
    \tl_put_left:Nn \l__mymodule_size_tl { [ }
```

This is rather ugly, in my opinion.  Is there anything better that I can do?

Comment: Are you looking for `\tl_set:Nx \l__mymodule_size_tl { [ \exp_not:c { \tl_use:N \l_keys_choice_tl } ] }`?

Comment: By the way, while it's not what *this particular* question asks for, future readers coming here because of the question title might be looking for `\exp_args:No \function:o {...}` which will pass double-o-expansion of `{...}` to `\function`.  (also alluded to in Joseph Wright's answer below) -- although note that x-expansion (or the "true twice-single-expansion" of `\expandafter\meaning\noexpand\empty` is different from the result of the "twice-o-expansion" above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In days of yore there was a `d`-type argument for double expansion. However, it was dropped some years ago as there were very few places it was required, particularly when the team decided not to use `toks` registers generally. From memory, in `expl3` there are two places where we had to go with a construct of the `\exp_args:NNo \exp_args:No` or similar form.

The reason that we did not keep `d`-type arguments is twofold. First, we want to avoid where possible relying on knowing the expansion detail of functions: this is required for low-level work but ideally should be relatively limited. The other reason is that it's very rarely needed as we have e-TeX available. The key to remember is that this allows us to control expansion in `x`-type contexts

```
\tl_set:Nx \l__mymodule_size_tl
  { [ \exp_not:c { \tl_use:N \l_keys_choice_tl } ] }
```

Whilst it is not needed here, we do document `\cs:w` ... `\cs_end:` for situations where exactly one expansion is required, so you could have

```
\tl_set:No \l__mymodule_size_tl
  { \exp_after:wN [ \cs:w \tl_use:N \l_keys_choice_tl \cs_end: ] }
```

though I would not use that here myself.

Comment: In an ideal world you would of course not be passing an argument here to a second document command (`\abs`) but to a code-level interface with a fixed number of mandatory arguments. Perhaps one day  ...

Answer (score 5):

My impression is that you want to do

```
\tl_set:Nx \l__mymodule_size_tl
 {
  [ \exp_not:c { \tl_use:N \l_keys_choice_tl } ]
 }
```

With `x` expansion `\exp_not:c` is triggered, so the argument is fully expanded as always when `c` is involved (it is `\csname...\endcsname`); then the resulting token is made not expandable, so if you have

```
size=big
```

you'll get `[\big]` in your token list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, `\exp_not:c` is exactly what I am looking for.  Both your and Joseph's answers are great!  But since I had to choose one to accept, I chose Joseph's since he covers double expansion.